# facebook share dialog (v2.0) does not promote user to login?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I am implementing a custom facebook share button with the new Facebook javascript SDK (v2.0 according to the docs in the developer center)

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxxxx',
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.0'
        });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function shareToFacebook(url) {
        var obj = {
            method: 'share',
            href: url,
        };
        function callback(response) { }
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
    }

    $('#mb-facebook').click(function () {

        shareToFacebook('http://some-url-to-share');

        return false;
    });
```

Now everything works fine exception one issue:

If I have logged into my facebook account before clicking the share to facebook button, then a popup window contains the expected facebook sharing form showed up, but if I do not log into my facebook account then click the share button, the a blank popup window contains nothing shows up, no promotion to log into facebook etc.

I do remember that I've done this before in another project that the share button will promote the user to log into facebook if he has not logged in yet.
So my question is : does facebook changed this behavior in the new SDK or I have missed something else?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search https://developers.facebook.com/bugs . There is a bug report about it

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/803655132980773/